# Error plotting spherical harmonics in MATLAB: Grid arrays must have NDGRID structure

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, spherical-coordinate, isosurface

I am trying to use the spherical harmonics to represent a perturbation of a spherical object in an acoustic and fluid flow in 3D.
So far, I have been able to use a 2D perturbation on a 3D spherical object, however, I would like to extend that.

The current code represents a 3D sphere with a 2D perturbation, so the perturbation is only in x and y:

```
clearvars; clc; close all;
Nx = 128;
Ny = 128;
Nz = 128; 
Lx =128; 
Ly = 128; 
Lz = 128; 
xi  = (0:Nx-1)/Nx*2*pi;
xi_x =  2*pi/Lx;
x =  xi/xi_x;
yi  = (0:Ny-1)/Ny*2*pi;
yi_y =  2*pi/Ly;
y = yi/yi_y;
zi  = (0:Nz-1)/Nz*2*pi;
zi_z =  2*pi/Lz;
z = zi/zi_z;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
A = 2*pi / Lx;
B = 2*pi / Ly;
C = 2*pi / Lz;
x0 = 64; 
y0 = 64;
z0 = 64; 
rx0 = 20; 
ry0 =  20; 
rz0 =  20;
p = 3;
b = 0.1; % pert amplitude 
c = 12; 
d = 1;
a = 4;
theta = atan2(Y -y0,  X-x0) - (pi/c);
p0 = ((X-x0) .* (X-x0)) /(rx0 * rx0) + ((Y-y0) .* (Y-y0))/(ry0 * ry0) + ((Z-z0) .* (Z-z0))/(rz0 * rz0);
Test =d + a * exp((-1. * p0 .* (1 - b .* cos(c * theta))).^p) ;
figure
isosurface(X,Y,Z,Test);
shading flat;
grid on;
```

Which returns the isosurface:

[image]

However, I would like to achieve something similar to this plot (perturbation in z as well):
[image]

This is my attempt using spherical harmonics to reproduce the above picture:

```
clearvars; clc; close all;
%in spherical coord
%calculate r
Nx = 128;  
Ny = 128;  
Nz = 128;
Lx =128; 
Ly = 128; 
Lz = 128; 
xi  = (0:Nx-1)/Nx*2*pi;
xi_x =  2*pi/Lx;
x =  xi/xi_x;
yi  = (0:Ny-1)/Ny*2*pi;
yi_y =  2*pi/Ly;
y = yi/yi_y;
zi  = (0:Nz-1)/Nz*2*pi;
zi_z =  2*pi/Lz;
z = zi/zi_z;
r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2); 
% Create the grid
delta = pi/127; 
%Taking for instance l=1, m=-1 you can generate this harmonic on a (azimuth, elevation) grid like this:
azimuths = 0 : delta : pi; 
elevations = 0 : 2*delta : 2*pi; 
[R, A, E] = ndgrid(r, azimuths, elevations); %A is phi and E is theta
H = 0.25 * sqrt(3/(2*pi)) .* exp(-1j*A) .* sin(E) .* cos(E);
%transform the grid back to cartesian grid like this:
%can also add some radial distortion to make things look nicer:
%the radial part depends on your domain
X = r .* cos(A) .* sin(E); 
Y = r .* sin(A) .* sin(E); 
Z = r .* cos(E); 
%parameters
x0 = 64;  
y0 = 64; 
z0 = 64;  
rx0 = 20; 
ry0 =  20; 
rz0 =  20;
p = 3;
b = 0.1; % pert amplitude 
%c = 12; 
d = 1;
a = 4;
p0 = ((X-x0) .* (X-x0)) /(rx0 * rx0) + ((Y-y0) .* (Y-y0))/(ry0 * ry0) + ((Z-z0) .* (Z-z0))/(rz0 * rz0);
Test1 =d + a * exp((-1. * p0 .*H).^p) ;
figure
isosurface(X,Y,Z,real(Test1)); %ERROR
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
Grid arrays must have NDGRID structure.
```

Is the issue in the way I am setting up the spherical harmonics? or the functional form of `Test1`?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you've created a NDGrid in the second code. In the first code that worked you created a meshgrid.

`isosurface` expects a grid in meshgrid format and transforms it later into an NDGrid format with `permute` just for the usage of the `griddedInterpolant` function. By the input of an NDGrid this operation will fail.

Why did you switch to creating a NDGrid? Did you get the same error when using `meshgrid`?

**EDIT**

OK, new theory: I think the problem is the grid itsself. Read the documentation on `ndgrid` for more information but for short: A NDGrid format is a completely rectangular grid where all nodes are exclusivly surrounded by 90° angles. By spanning up a grid with `ndgrid(r, azimuths, elevations)` or `meshgrid(r, azimuths, elevations)` you are getting this rectangular grid but of course this grid is meaningless because r, azimuths and elevations represent spherical coordinates. By later converting R, A and E into the carthesian coordinates X, Y and Z you get a propper spherical grid but the grid isn't a NDGrid structure anymore since it's not rectangular anymore.

So you have to find a workaround to calculate with your spherical grid.

- Maybe you can use another function to visualize your data that dosn't take any grid format as input
- Or maybe you can try working with a rectangular cartesian grid by setting all values outside the sphere to 0. (You have to refine your grid accordingly to achieve a good estimation of the sphere)

Comment: This returns the error unfortunately, ``Error using griddedInterpolant
Grid arrays must have NDGRID structure.

Error in interp3 (line 144)
            F = griddedInterpolant(X, Y, Z, V, method,extrap);

Error in isonormals (line 79)
        n(:,1)=interp3(x, y, z, nx, verts(:,1), verts(:,2), verts(:,3));

Error in isosurface (line 133)
    isonormals(x,y,z,data, p);

Error in 
isosurface(X,Y,Z,real(Test1));``

Comment: @Jamie why do you use r instead of R to calculate X, Y and Z ?

Comment: @Jamie I editet my answer with a new theory